# Custom UIButton disappears when linked as IBOutlet in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I created a custom table view cell called `SellerMobileTableViewCell` which displays a seller's mobile number as a label, and SMS and Call round rect buttons:

[image: SellerMobileTableViewCell]

The cell doesn't have its own XIB file--it's a prototype cell in a `UITableView` with the custom class set to `SellerMobileTableViewCell`. `SellerMobileTableViewCell` contains the two buttons as `IBOutlet`s of type `ContactButton`. In interface builder, I have also already set the buttons to `ContactButton` as its custom class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ContactButton.h"

@interface SellerMobileTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ContactButton *SMSButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ContactButton *callButton;

@end
```

Here's the problem: The two custom buttons appear in the app when I don't connect them to `SellerMobileTableViewCell.h` via Ctrl-Click and dragging to the `IBOutlet`s. However, when I do, and as I should, they don't appear at all.

I don't understand why that's happening. Help?

Comment: Are you using autoLayout? If Not please try it..

Comment: Yes, I'm using Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `UITableView` delegate and dataSource in your XIB file and the protocols in the header file?

```
 @interface MerchantListController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

[image]

Also did you set the cell identifier?

[image]

You also need to set the delegate methods of `UITableView`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.merchantList count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MerchantListCell";
    MerchantListCell    *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[[MerchantListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    }


    // initialize cell data here


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the view controller holding the table view is actually a `UITableViewController`. Those are automatically set.

Comment: Ok, did you set the `UITableView` protocols and the required delegate methods? Also did you set the Cell identifier?

Comment: When the File's Owner is a `UITableViewController`, I don't have to set it myself as the delegate and the data source (the two protocols). I have also set the cell identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that this doesn't count as a "good" StackOverflow answer, but it works now, and I didn't do anything too differently.

First, I tried to take Vin's suggestion. Even if I wasn't hiding the `IBOutlet` anywhere in my file, I decided to set it to `NO` in `SellerMobileTableViewCell.m` just to be safe:

```
#import "SellerMobileTableViewCell.h"

@implementation SellerMobileTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    self.SMSButton.hidden = NO;
    return self;
}

// ...

@end
```

Then I also deleted the following method which was automatically created in `SellerMobileTableViewCell.m`:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

However, I removed the line `self.SMSButton.hidden = NO` again and put back the `setSelected:` method, and it still worked. In short, I put everything back to where it was. I really don't understand this error.

Might this be an Xcode bug? I first experienced strange things happening ever since I added the custom images which I set as backgrounds of the custom buttons. I had `CopyPNGFile Error`s which, if you Google around, are one of the strangest Xcode bugs which can be solved by saving the PNG files as non-interlaced. However, I just lost that error in Issue Navigator without doing anything with the images themselves as well--I simply deleted and re-added the files.